# Дублирование при заполниение input элементов

Tags: javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/gxy45/1320/
Помогите,кто может,
Нужно чтоб при заполнении одного из инпутов в других инпуктах заполнялось тоже.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

не увидел там заполнения, но что бы табы заставить работать, нужно заменить одну строку кода

```
$('#wrapper a').click(function() {
```

на

```
$('#wrapper a,#wrapper input').click(function() {
```

Comment: Простите код перепутал,вот тут как сделать чтоб при заполнении одного из инпутов в других инпуктах заполнялось тоже.

Comment: Ребята,ну кто нибудь,дай-те хотяб какой-то совет

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/gxy45/1324/

```
$('#wrapper').on('input', function (evt) {
    var inp = evt.target;
    $('input', this).each(function () {
        if (this !== inp) {
            this.value = inp.value;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Повесьте на keydown например, функцию, копирующую value из целевого инпута, во все остальные